# In Perl, how can I write the output of Dumper to a file?

Tags: perl, debugging, dump, data-dumper

How can I make [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) write a dump into a file?

Comment: `Dumper()` simply outputs a string, use it like any other string going to a file (see below).

Comment: i have huge dump value , so i need to keep that into file and having look .

Comment: @JACK I agree with your point

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't forget that you can specify the file handle to `print` to as in

```
print $LOG Dumper( \%some_complex_hash );
```

or use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Slurp):

```
write_file 'mydump.log', Dumper( \%some_complex_hash );
```

**Further thoughts:** You might want to get into the habit of using:

```
warn Dumper( \%some_complex_hash );
```

and redirecting standard error to a file when you invoke your script (how you do this depends on the shell). For example:

```
 C:\Temp> sdf.pl 2>dump
```

Comment: I'm curious: what advantage does File::Slurp offer here?

Comment: If all I want is to dump a complex data structure to a file for debugging purposes, it is more self contained than open / print / close: no filehandles or error messages to mess with.

Comment: @SinanÜnür how is  $LOG supposed to be used. should $LOG point to a file 
open ($LOG, '>', 'file.txt');

Comment: @patz `$LOG` is a file handle, as I clearly state up front.

Answer (score 8):

The question is a bit unclear, but are you looking for something like this?

```
open my $FH, '>', 'outfile';
print $FH Dumper(\%data);
close $FH;
```

You can restore the data later by using [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

Comment: For storing and restoring later, Storable is a much better idea than Data::Dumper + eval: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable

Comment: Telemachus is correct.  Storable, YAML, JSON, DBM::Deep or any of one million other serialization modules is a better choice than Data::Dumper + eval.

Answer (score 8):

Use [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

```
print FILE Data::Dumper->Dump($object);
```